# How accessibility works inside for iOS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Have you seen any information about internals of iOS accessibility?

I am looking for some unofficial documentation which shows how it's integrated with other parts of operation system.

Generally, I can reverse engineer it, but it will take a lot of time, because there are bunch of pieces:

- Accessibility bundles
- Preference bundle associated with accessibility
- Accessibility private frameworks (several of them)
- Accessibility library
- Several daemons which provide some services for accessibility

So, I am looking for unofficial documentation which has at least high level overview of how this components play with each other.

Comment: Just a quick question. There is documentation for other private APIs of iOS? Haven't come across any (have only been working with CT and MobileSMS though)

Comment: I don't think there is one place with the documentation. It's very scattered. I found small bits in different places.

Comment: Yes I guess you're right. And what you are looking for, is kinda specific. Can only find bits and pieces around the web! Wishing you luck and hope to see an answer here. Really interesting question.